# How do we know that this matrix product produces a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm following a derivation in a textbook and I'm getting tripped up on one of the steps. $O$ is an objective function that we're trying to minimize, $V$ is a $k\times1$ vector, $k$ is a positive integer, $U$ is a $k\times2$ matrix, $p$ is a $2\times1$ vector, and $^T$ is the matrix transpose operation.

In the text, they go from
$$ O = (V - Up)^T(V - Up) \,,$$
to
$$ O = V^TV - 2V^TUp + p^TU^TUp \,.$$

The part I'm stuck on is the middle term: $2V^TUp$. When I expand the original expression I get
$$ O = V^TV - p^TU^TV - V^TUp + p^TU^TUp\,.$$

The only way that I can see them arriving at this result is if $V^TUp$ is symmetric, i.e. 
$$V^TUp = (V^TUp)^T = p^TU^TV \,.$$
However, the author doesn't provide any statement or proof that this is the case. My background is in engineering not math, so maybe it's obvious to a mathematician.

**How do we know that $V^TUp$ is symmetric?**

Comment: What is the size of $V^{T}Up$?  That is, how many rows and columns does it have?

Comment: Formally is $O$ a matrix, but it is a $(1×k).(k×1)$. Therefore is $O$ a number, and all composants are numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V^TUp$ is symmetric because it's a $1 \times 1$ matrix!

Comment: Well, I guess it was obvious... whoops. Thanks for your help! I will accept in 5 min (have to wait out the timer).